# Modify the image to run with a user other than root [.net core]

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

We scanned our image with a vulnerability tool and we get this message "Modify the image to run with a user other than root"

We tried several things, creating a directory, creating a user and setting the user to the new one. We get several errors depending on the "solution" we try, I am happy to share them if necessary. I am starting to thing that there is a more basic issue with our dockerfile

The dockerfile

```
1. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal as build
2. 
3. ENV APP_USER app_user
4. ENV HOME /home/$APP_USER
5. RUN useradd -r $APP_USER
6. 
7. RUN mkdir -p $HOME/src
8. WORKDIR $HOME/src
9. 
10. COPY "./nuget.config" ./
11. COPY "./Directory.Build.props" ./
12. COPY "./src/Services/BookStore/" .
13. 
14. USER root
15. RUN chown -R $APP_USER $HOME/src
16. 
17. # Set user name to run container
18. USER $APP_USER
19. WORKDIR ./BookStore.Api
20. RUN dotnet build "BookStore.Api.csproj"
21. 
22. EXPOSE 80
23. ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
24. 
25. FROM build AS publish
26. RUN dotnet publish "BookStore.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
27. WORKDIR /app/publish
28. RUN rm -f *.pdb && rm -f *Development*.* && rm -f nuget.config
29. 
30. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS release
31. WORKDIR /app
32. COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
33. EXPOSE 80
34. ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BookStore.Api.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```

Errors:

- having the user on line 18: we get the error "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/app_user/.dotnet' is denied**" on building the image
- having the user on line 21: the image builds and we get following error on runtime

*NuGet.targets(565,5): error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/6d5da057f9063f4d1ecd1b43e767d61dce14616c' for operations on '/home/app_user/src/nuget.config'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/6d5da057f9063f4d1ecd1b43e767d61dce14616c' will allow NuGet to continue*

- Having the user on line 35: solved all build and runtime issues, but fails the scanning for obvious reasons.. :)

I tried many more fixes, found on SO and github posts, without any luck
What am I missing?

Comment: can you try build first, then add user and chown?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544469/how-to-run-net-core-2-application-in-docker-on-linux-as-non-root/53544813

Comment: @LeiYang I don't think doing that will change the result of the scan, it will be similar to the third point of the question

Comment: You need to add user creation and `USER` directive to result image (release), not build image. For example, line 31 (after workdir), you will create user and set user of container and then your app will work under non-root user permissions.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but why are you using `sdk` as your base image for the release stage of your Dockerfile?  Why didn't you choose to use a runtime-only base like `aspnet` or `runtime`.

Comment: @MattThalman thank you! asking the question has several goals, i am a beginner at this and i wanted to capture any other mistakes :)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten thank you, ill try this now, makes sence

Comment: @ExplodingKitten thank you! your suggestion solved my issue, you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add user creation and `USER` directive to result image (release), not build image. For example, line 31 (after `WORKDIR`), you will create user and set user of container and then your app will work under non-root user permissions.

Something like:

```
#...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS release
WORKDIR /app
ENV APP_USER app_user
RUN useradd -r $APP_USER
USER $APP_USER
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BookStore.Api.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```